# Django: How to keep the test database when the test is finished?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing

**Some of my requirements are these:**

- Create a in-memory sqlite3 database.
- Read a list, and pull those data from
  production database.
- Perform unit tests
- Remain the test database.
- Perform some intelligent UI tests using the same test database.

I am not a pro in test, but these have to achieved, anyone professional who can suggest a **best practice** in this area?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run:

```
./manage.py testserver
```

Your test database will be created, all your tests are run and afterwards the server keeps running, so you can do your ui testing.

hope this helps,
Anton

Comment: Runs a development server with data from the given fixture(s). E.g.: ./manage.py testserver test_data.json

Comment: This is inaccurate - ./manage.py testserver does _not_ run all your Django unittests for you. Yes it enables UI testing against a blank, fresh database each time but the unittests are not triggered.

Answer (score 36):

New in Django 1.8

> The --keepdb option can be used to preserve the test database between test runs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---keepdb

Comment: How to keep database structure without keeping the actual data?

Answer (score 1):

[Persistent Database Test Runner](http://django-test-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/keep_database_runner.html) adds a new command called `quicktest` that will retain the database after the test is run, and use the same when run again.